# If $f$ is bounded and $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=\infty$, then $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)g(x)=\infty.$

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove or give counter example of the following claim:

> If $f$ is bounded and $\lim\limits_{x\to c}g(x)=\infty$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)g(x)=\infty.$

Would it be enough to have $f(x)$ with a limit of zero for a counter example?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: I have tried to improve your post using TeX (for better readability). Please check whether these edits did not unintentionally change the meaning of your post.

Comment: Yes, it would be enough to give one counterexample.

Comment: [Closely related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/563170/28900).

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessarily enough that $f(x)$ have a limit of $0,$ as $g$ may "grow too fast" for $f$ to make up for it. Consider for example the functions $g(x)=\dfrac1{x^2}$ and $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$ with $c=0.$

You do have the right idea, though. Think about constant functions....

Comment: Thank you very much for help! I think I got it now!

Comment: You are very welcome! If you like, you can "accept" my answer by clicking the check mark on my post. This will get points for both of us, and indicate to other users that the question has been satisfactorily answered.

Answer (score 0):

Really late counter example, but the function $f,g:[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ are good to look at. It can be shown that $f$ is bounded and $g$ is unbounded. Since each function is not, zero, then we can say $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)g(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}x^2\frac{1}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}1=1 $$