# If a limit of a function exists and the limit of the product with another function exists, prove the limit of the second function exist.

Tags: limits

> If $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$$ exists and $$\lim_{x\to a} \big(f(x)g(x)\big)$$ exists, then $$\lim_{x\to a} g(x)$$ exists.

Please explain why the above statement is true or false.

EDIT: Edited question to be more specific.

Comment: you probably mean "doesn't always exist"

Comment: @ dkuper: you are correct, fixed.

Comment: **Hint:** Think about suitable powers of $x$.

Comment: [Closely related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/545993/28900).

Answer (score 2):

Take $a=0$, $g(x)=\sin(1/x)$, and try to find an $f$ that makes it work.

Answer (score 2):

What if $f$ goes to $0$, but $g$ has a jump discontinuity at $a$?

Also, notice by the quotient rule that if the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to a$ isn’t $0$, the limit of $g(x)$ as $x\to a$ must exist.